# How to write a batch file to run applications opening in different command prompts?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to run three servers on my Windows machine from command prompt. For this I would like to write a batch file to run these opening three different command prompts.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `run 3 servers from command prompt` and `opening three different command prompts`?

Comment: basically 3 applications should be opened using three different command windows and they keep on running

Answer (score 1):

To generate 3 new CMD windows that remain open, use the following command syntax:

```
start "application1" cmd.exe /k dir *.exe
start "application2" cmd.exe /k dir *.xml
start "application3" cmd.exe /k dir *.bat
```

Where the command after `/k` is whatever application command line that you want to launch.

Replace the "application#" with some TITLE for the window, that makes sense for you (otherwise it will just say something like C:\Windows\System32\CMD.exe).

The windows will stay open, but that doesn't mean your application will still be running.  Like the `Dir` examples above, it may end but the window will remain.

*The full command syntax for START is found [here](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

The full command syntax for CMD is found [here](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html).*

Answer (score 0):

Why batch?

If you can, my best suggestion would be to ditch batch and download cygwin in order to use bash instead.

You will find bash much more flexible, used (which means you are far more likely to get support from others), and supported.

I am a windows user and tried to learn batch some time ago, but it was really really frustrating. bash is so much more user friendly.

Comment: Did you get what I meant?? If you understood could you please give me some example opening 3 applications using 3 different command windows

Comment: In order to make it work you should install cygwin, an utility that allows you to use many unix tool on windows. http://www.cygwin.com/ I was very skeptic towards this, but I found it very good indeed.
I am not very knowledgeable yet in bash, so I strongly advise that you re-ask the question replacing "batch" with "bash in cygwin".Surely someone more expert than me will answer.
<pre><code>
Try the following
    #! /bin/bash
    shell=/path/to/shell
    prog1=/path/to/prog1
    prog2=/path/to/prog2
    prog3=/path/to/prog3

    ./$shell $prog1
    ./$shell $prog2
    $shell $prog3
</code></pre>

Comment: An irrelevant answer to OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want

```
start application1
start application2
start application3
```

This will start 3 applications which will open with 3 different command prompts, whether or not they will keep running or not will depend on the app.